# Android Studio error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-2.2

I recently started learning and trying to develop android apps.(total beginner, im in the "Hello Word" stage)
But the android studio keeps hitting with errors.
This is the error i get when i start a new project.

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Please read the following process output to find out more-----------------------
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

I cant find my way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change  the graddle.properties file to Xmx1024m
you can find the solution in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT3sHXVWjIU